# how add a new input for each checked box? - Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code HTML and PHP in my project (codeigniter):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <?php foreach($hardware as $hardware): ?>                                      
        <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$hardware['id_elemento']?>" name="hardware[]" value="<?           =$hardware['id_elemento']?>">
        <label class="mx-2" for="<?=$hardware['id_elemento']?>"><?=$hardware['elemento']?>               </label>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad" id="mname" name="mname" class="form-control         col-2" />
      <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('29');
var input = document.getElementById('mname');
checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (input.style.display != 'block') {
        input.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        input.style.display = '';
    }
});
```

What i want to do is add a new input for each checked box.. each new input type number is a quantity of each hardware what i want to check in the list, but with this code i just make a one input.. each checkbox have a differents ID's (29, 30, 31, 32) .. equals to hardware[] and the input with name/id: quantity[]

how i can do this for each one? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an event (onchange) on checkboxes.
2. If the clicked checkbox is now checked start a function.
3. This function has to create a custom input that fit to your needs :

   `var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("class", "foo"); //etc...`
4. And finally appends it where you want : `yourdiv.appendChild(input)`

   Example :

   ```
   var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");

   checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
       if(this.checked) {
           // Checkbox is checked..
       } 
   });
   ```